# jQuery after show() assumes that display:inline is :hidden. Why?

Tags: jquery, hidden, element

With jQuery 1.4.2, :hidden filter is not filtering out elements that were hidden, but i've made then visible by calling show(). Filter assumes it is still hidden.

Is this bug or am i missing something? Consider the following code:

```
$("td.ms-authoringcontrols > span[id*='_ParallelApprovers']:hidden:first").css("display")
"none"
$("td.ms-authoringcontrols > span[id*='_ParallelApprovers']:hidden:first").show()
Object
$("td.ms-authoringcontrols > span[id*='_ParallelApprovers']:hidden:first").css("display")
"inline" // ?? Let me scratch my head...
$("td.ms-authoringcontrols > span[id*='_ParallelApprovers']:hidden:first").is(":hidden")
true //element with "display:inline", visible in browser, but yet it is hidden
```

Instead of "inline", you would expect "none", because :hidden filter was used.

What it does is from an array of objects it selects first hidden element. Each time i call these lines of code, i expect them to select next hidden element (not the one i just showed).

Comment: you seriously should read an article about `performance & selectors`. The selectors you using, basically, can't be worse.

Comment: I have no option but to select where ID contains, because ASP.NET modifies ID to ClientID (Adds parent ID prefixes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would be correct assuming the `.show()` happened linearly.  However `.show()` starts an animation that ends with the object being shown. If you would like to execute code after it has shown use the alternative form with a animation length and a callback `.show(100,function(){})`.

Comment: Thank you. When i specified animation length, it now works as expected.